# Calling javascript function when tab is selected

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

Is is possible to load the contents of a tab using a javascript function and then have that function called when the tab header is clicked passing it whatever parameters need to be passed, rather than embedding similar javascript code for each of these tabs?  I have 5 different tabs where each tab I would like to show graphs using a charting software.  The catch for this charting software is needs javascript to render the images on the browser.

Below is an example of the 2 scripts needed to render and show 1 chart.  The only thing that changes per script is the .xml and the .swf.  Since this code is similar for all charts, like I said before, I'd like to call this via a function if possible.

```
<div id="chartdiv">Chart Data.</div>
<div id="fcexpDiv" align="right">FusionCharts Export Handler Component</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myChart = new FusionCharts("Column3D.swf", "myChartId", "500", "300", "0", "1");
    myChart.setXMLUrl("Data_EXPORT.xml");
    myChart.render("chartdiv");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myExportComponent = new FusionChartsExportObject("fcExporter1", "FCExporter.swf");
    myExportComponent.Render("fcexpDiv");
</script>
```

I.E: Incase you're wondering, the charting software is FusionCharts

Comment: In the future, please try to format your code properly.

Comment: To answer your question: yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JS Library, like jQuery, plus UI, like http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/#tabs1-js